# Maintaining a repository of binary files

Tags: software-rec, repository

I have a bunch of files in proprietary format (.pdf, .doc, .wmv, etc) that I want to mirror on a server I have, for archival purposes as well as to be able to pull down the "asset repository" to another computer (from the server).

Basically I want GIT but for binary files.  It would be nice if a revision history could be maintained for the Word documents (every "push" to the server overwrites the copy on the server but secretly the old copy would be saved somewhere).

The simplest thing is to use FTP, but it seems like an annoying way to manage, to have to manually rename the documents etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe rsync with the --backup option

http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html

Answer (score 0):

Yu can use git (or svn, or...) for binary files. Just that (at least in git's case) non-text files can't ge stored efficiently as differences between versions, so the repository will grow like the sum of the file's version sizes.